# C# Custom display arrangement settings

Tags: c#, screen, display, resolution

So I am trying to make a little utility for managing my screens, I want to add a screen rearrangement system like in windows, see here: [Windows Display Rearangment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clrdv.png), I already have code worked out for getting and setting the exact screen coordinates I need, however I need to work out some sort of rearrangement dragging system that "snaps" to position like the windows implementation.

so far I have made some basic strides towards this, before coming to the realization the snapping will be a bit challenging, so here is the code I have so far, and here is an attached screenshot of the program as is. It consists of a panel with 3 panels inside it. For now I would like tips on when the mouse is released and the collision checks are run to snap similarly to windows display rearangment, Just a test bed for now, I am aware that this example of my test bed will currently only work with the dragging of the 3rd panel testing against the other 2 static panels, I will implement the functionality for all screens once we solve the issue :) [Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td3Q8.png)

```
    private Point MouseDownLocation;
private void panel2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     var pan = (Panel)sender;
     if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
     {
          pan.Left = e.X + pan.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
          pan.Top = e.Y + pan.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
     }
}

        private void panel2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                var pan = (Panel)sender;
                List<Panel> allpanels = new List<Panel>();
                foreach (Panel pancomp in panel1.Controls)
                {
                    if (pancomp == pan)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }      
                    allpanels.Add(pancomp);
                }


                //var pan = (Panel)sender;
                List<Panel> collisions = new List<Panel>();

                foreach (Panel pancomp in allpanels)
                {
                    if (pancomp == pan)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (pan.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pancomp.Bounds))
                    {
                        //PUSH AWAY
                        collisions.Add(pancomp);
                        //listBox1.Items.Add("collided!");//panel2.Location.ToString());
                    }
                }

                collisions = collisions;

                if (collisions.Count > 0)
                {
                    //WE HAVE COLLISIONS LETS SNAP TO VALID PLACE
                    //MouseDownLocation



                }
                else
                {
                    //WE HAVE NO COLLISIONS LETS SNAP TO PLACE
                }


            }
        }

        private void panel2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            }
        }
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)
Regards
James